# Redux useSelector with Conditional statement

Tags: redux, local-storage, react-hooks, redux-persist

I need to get Redux store data but not always and different data for each component instantiate.
How can I use useSelector with Conditional statement?

The component should get data from store only when some child components are rendered and also different data each time depending on the child component.

Answer (score 15):

useSelector takes in a callback that has access to the redux state as an argument

so assuming you control whether the child component is rendered in a boolean flag called isComponentRendered, and want to select data when it is true and else nothing, you could try the following:

```
const data = useSelector(state => {
   if(state.isComponentRendered) {
       return state.data
   }
   return null;
})
```

Comment: I think it's a workaround. Is it good practice to put a **if** inside a useSelector?

Comment: useSelector is a hook hence calling it inside an if statement would be a react hooks rule violation. For more info please refer to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).
That leaves you with the above code as the only place within the component to apply a conditional logic.